# Reading from database in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, controller, laravel-blade

How can I get the image url stored in my database and render it on the page in laravel 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very vague question, so will be the answer. Please clarify if it's not what you need.

Assumptions: You have an Item model that is stored in a DB. In the relevant controller method you add the code below which will find the item with id 1 and will display the field named "url".

```
$item = Item::whereId(1)->first();
echo $item->url;
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I just couldn't understand the flow of data. So I put up a vague question.